# How to put condition in Codeigniter 4 model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, conditional-statements, codeigniter-4

I have this model in Codeigniter 4.

```
class CommentsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';


    protected $allowedFields = ['com_user', 'com_email', 'com_phone', 'comment'];


}
```

and this route

```
public function comments()
    {    
        $model = new CommentsModel();

        $data = [
            'comments' => $model->paginate(50),
            'pager' => $model->pager
        ];



        echo view('templates/header');
        echo view('templates/aside');
        return view('comments', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
```

I want to put condition **WHERE** so that this will get only comments that meet with the condition....Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Where` clause in active records to get what you want.

```
public function comments()
{    
    $model = new CommentsModel();
    $model = $model->where('com_user','john');
    $data = [
        'comments' => $model->paginate(50),
        'pager' => $model->pager
    ];



    echo view('templates/header');
    echo view('templates/aside');
    return view('comments', $data);
    echo view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @vsol modify your function code, and try to execute.

Comment: I have this but didn't work `class Comments extends Controller
{
    public function comments()
 {    
    $model = new CommentsModel();
    $model = $model->where('com_status','1')->findAll();
    $data = [
        'comments' => $model->paginate(50),
        'pager' => $model->pager
    ];



    echo view('templates/header');
    echo view('templates/aside');
    return view('comments', $data);
    echo view('templates/footer');
 }
}`


error

Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: @hardwood kindly when it is time to join two tables where two columns do have the same name in both the tables (tables 'user' and 'dept' with both having clumns 'id' and 'name'). I think it is matter of MySQL aliases, how and where do you kindly place the alias statements? And hopefully the join. Mean using the model class approach, so exactly as in this thread with $model = new CommentsModel(); approach. Thank you